# Expected value of a state $\psi$, with two eigenstates

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

If a state is generally given as $$\vert{\psi}\rangle=a\vert0\rangle+b\vert1\rangle$$

then what is ( If the question makes sense ) the expected value of this state? I know about the expected value of operators and variables, but not of individual states.

Comment: By my limited understanding it should be $a^{2}+b^{2}$ since (upon measurement) the system is either in state $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$. $a^{2}$ may be interpreted as the probability that it's in state $|0\rangle$, $b^{2}$ is the probability it's in state $|1\rangle$ so $a^{2}+b^{2}$ is the probability that it's in one of the two states.

Comment: "Expected value" is probably to vague. If the state is normalized, its norm is 1. You'll need to provide an operator to get more info than that.

Comment: I assume you mean the expectation value and the definition of an expectation value of an operator is 
$$
\langle \hat O\rangle_\psi   = \langle \psi|\hat O | \psi \rangle.
$$
Plug in your state into the right hand side and expand the terms. If your basis states are eigenstates of the operator, you can evaluate the terms and simplify further.

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no such thing as the expectation value of a state by itself. Measurable quantities, or observables, correspond to Hermitian operators (over the Hilbert space of the system) in quantum mechanics. So, one speaks of the values of an observable for a given state.

In particular, if a given state is in an eigenstate of a Hermitian operator then it corresponds to the corresponding observable having a definite value over the given state. On the other hand, if a given state is not an eigenstate of a Hermitian operator then there is no definite value of the corresponding observable over the given state. However, one can still measure such an observable over the given state and the outcome of the measurement will be one of the eigenvalues of the corresponding Hermitian operator with a probability given by the Born rule. Thus, we can define an expectation value of an observable over a given state which is the average of the outcomes of an infinite number of measurements of the observable over infinitely many identical copies of the given state. Of course, one can talk about the expectation value of an observable regardless of whether the given state is an eigenstate of the corresponding Hermitian operator or not -- the expectation value will simply be the eigenvalue of the corresponding Hermitian operator associated with the given state if the state is an eigenstate of the corresponding Hermitian operator.

So, in summary, we only talk about the values of observables over a given state -- there is no such thing as the value of a state by itself. Consequently, there is no such thing as an expectation value of a given state by itself. A state is not something that you measure in quantum mechanics -- it is an object that gives you probabilities for the various outcomes of what you can measure, i.e., observables.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it makes much sense to think about the expected value of a $\textit{state}$. When we talk about expected values, it relates to what we expect the average outcome from $\textit{measurements}$ to be when we perform many such measurements on our state of interest.

Comment: No, we don't expect the output of a measurement to be the expectation value. For example, an expectation value doesn't even need to be an eigenvalue of the operator.

Comment: My bad, forgot to include the part about averaging...

Comment: Thanks! Removed my negative vote. :)

Answer (score 0):

The statement definitely does not make sense on the face of it. What is clear is that a measurement basis $\{ |0\rangle, |1\rangle\}$ (observer reference frame, projection-valued measure (PVM)) is given. Then, any labeling (by reals) of those events will give a self-adjoint operator that we conventionally associate with a physical observable. Then, one can discuss the expected value of such an observable (in fact, all such labelings are connected with a $C^\star-$algebra generated by the given PVM).

Answer (score -1):

Let you're operator be $\hat{O}$ and $\vert0\rangle$ have eigenvalue $\lambda_0$ and $\vert1\rangle$ have eigenvalue $\lambda_1$. Then the expectation value of $\hat{O}$ is

$$\langle\hat{O}\rangle=(a\langle0\vert+b\langle1\vert)\hat{O}(a\vert0\rangle+b\vert1\rangle)=(a\langle0\vert+b\langle1\vert)(a\lambda_0\vert0\rangle+b\lambda_1\vert1\rangle)$$

Since $\vert 0\rangle$ and $\vert 1 \rangle$ are ortonormal, then the cross terms cancel out to zero and the matching bra kets yield 1.

So the final result is :

$$\langle\hat{O}\rangle=a^*a\lambda_0+b^*b\lambda_1$$

The weighted average of the eigenvalues of each state.

For an individual component state, the expected value is the eigenvalue since measurements of that state can only ever produce that value there's a 100% change of getting it.